# Gnuplot key positioning within box with wide title

Tags: gnuplot

I have a key with a wide title:

[image]

This was generated using the following:

```
set key ins vert reverse t r R title "Starting values for (x,y)" box
```

I would like the text within the key box to be aligned to the right within the box, but using `help key` I can't find any option to position the text within the box.

How do I solve this?

Comment: It seems that specifying an absolute width of the legend (something like `width 10` before the `title` keyword) will right-justify the label text. You will probably end up with a large space between the line and the label, but you can make the line longer with the `samplen` option. Alternatively you can split your 7 legend entries into two columns by specifying `maxrows 4`.

Comment: A line break would help, although it's not the solution: `title "Starting values\nfor (x,y)"`

Comment: @user8153 Thanks, indeed I get a large space between line and label, but it looks slightly better.

Answer (score 1):

it mostly depends which version of Gnuplot you are using, 5.2 seems to offer a solution:

> An overall title can be put on the key (`title "<text>"`)---see also
>   `syntax`  for the distinction between text in single- or
>   double-quotes. The justification  of the title defaults to center and
>   can be changed by the keywords `right` or  `left`

older versions (such as 4.6) do not seem to support this...